# How to create a branch recursive?

Tags: clearcase

I am creating a sub branch from main branch using the below command. It work fine if the source name contains no space in between. But if a source name contains a blank space in between then it wont create the sub branch. Any idea.

running below command from Dos prompt

```
Cleartool find <<path where I should start branching>> -nxname -exec "cleartool mkbranch -c "comments" -nco TEST_BRANCH %CLEARCASE_PN%"
```

For ex:- 
if my cleaar contains the source

- ABC (source)
- ABC DEF (single file name)
- CD&AB (single file name)

If I run the above command it will create a sub branch for ABC and for other 2 it wont branch. It throws an error :- cannot find the path name.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some double-quotes (for windows `cleartool` commands):

```
cleartool find <<path where I should start branching>> -nxname
  -exec "cleartool mkbranch -c "comments" -nco TEST_BRANCH \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Note the '`\"`' around the `%CLEARCASE_PN%` (representing the 'PathName' of a clearcase element).

I also tried 'triple double-quotes' successfully before:

```
cleartool find <<path where I should start branching>> -nxname
  -exec "cleartool mkbranch -c "comments" -nco TEST_BRANCH """%CLEARCASE_PN%""""
```